# Create a secondary id autoincrement or a parameter based on a parent entity - Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, hibernate

In the API in Spring Boot that I'm developing I have a parent entity that has a one to many relation with the child entity (One parent can have n children). My problem is that I have a lot of those children and I would like to have something like a **secondary id** that autoincrements starting from 1 for each parent. Other option would be creating a key based on the name of the parent element.

To explain it better I would like something like this, where my parent is Compania and the child is office (id would be the real DB id while idExtra would be the newly added id):

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "companiaONE",
    "office": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "idExtra": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "idExtra": "2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "idExtra": "3"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "idExtra": "4"
      }
    ]
  }

{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "companiaTWO",
    "office": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "idExtra": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "idExtra": "2"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "idExtra": "3"
      }
    ]
  }
```

So, is this possible? In this case, how could I achieve it?

Thanks!

edit. To explain it better, right now, the user searches for the child element using the **id** of that child and the id of the Compania.

So for example my user does this: ***GET /companias/4/office/65*** and maybe that office he is searching is the 4th one of the compania. So it would be easier to just point to the extra id that is the idExtra: "4" and use ***companias/4/office/4***. That's why I'd like to create a new parameter based on the parent.

Comment: actually you want to have a row count for every child of a parent ? 
for example ```child1, child2, child3``` ?
what's your requirement exactly ?

Comment: @ZahraAsgharzade I've just updated the post to explain it better, but yeah, I would like something like that, thanks!